# How should I understand the following passage?

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

I'm so confused about the following passage.

How should I take this part 'have availed and wrought for humanity in other creeds'?

Is Divine Presences a subject of 'have availed and wrought'?

Please, explain this to me simply.

The passage:

> In the beloved person of the Buddha were enshrined all that Divine
> Presences, wisdom stooping from on high, transcendent love and power
> mighty and willing to save, the secret of genius knowing and drawing
> the hearts of men, the ideal Superman, have availed and wrought for
> humanity in other creeds.

Source: Buddhism
P. 50
:by Mrs. Rhys Davids

Comment: It's not trying hard to be clear. A translation? All the Divine Presences (the Gods fashioned by and to people of other religions) are built into the ideal of the Buddha.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin, thanks. What does the phrase 'for humanity in other creeds' mean?

Comment: I’ve deleted my answer in deference to Anton Sherwood’s. I do concur in  Yosef Baskin’s verdict that it’s not trying hard to be clear.

Comment: "Humanity in other creeds" means those who follow other religions (creeds).

Comment: *for humanity in other creeds* is not a phrase.  “those things that Divine Presences in other creeds have done for humanity”, is that clearer?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I think it's to be understood as "wrought, in other creeds, for humanity" that is, things wrought for humanity, as set forth in the teachings of other creeds.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *Divine Presences* is the subject of *availed and wrought*.  Everything between the first comma and the last is illustrative examples of Divine Presences.

Guessing at the context, I think the sentence means to say: other religions may separate the symbols or personifications of wisdom, love, power and so on, but in Buddhism the Buddha himself is the symbol of all of these.

Comment: I would tend to agree with you on the subject, but a transitive verb **avail** would normally have as the subject those things that are beneficial, not as we find there, "all that Divine Presences have availed ...for humanity".

Comment: The head start he was given availed him nothing.